# How to divide two Array of Arrays and prevent zero division

Tags: ruby

I have the following sample data.

Basically I need to divide each data in the variable distribuitions by the data field in the variable entrance.

```
distribuitions = [{:name=>"cardio", :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 0], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 0], ["11", 0.39e2], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]},
 {:name=>"shape", :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 0], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 0], ["11", 0.394e2], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}]

entrance = {:name=>"gym_entrance", :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 0], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 0], ["11", 0.176e3], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}
```

I have written this function but I can't prevent 0 division.

```
def divide_distribuition_set_by(distribuitions, d)
  distribuitions.each do |distribuition|
    collection = [distribuition[:data], d]
    hours, attendance = collection.map { |x| x.transpose }.transpose
    hours.first.zip(attendance.transpose.map { |col| col.reduce(:/) })
  end
end
```

Expected result ( all values of data are divided by the field data in the entrance variable

```
[{:name=>"cardio", :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 0], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 0], ["11", 0.2215909090909091,], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]},
     {:name=>"shape", :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 0], ["08", 0], ["09", 0], ["10", 0], ["11", 0.22386363636363635,], ["12", 0], ["13", 0], ["14", 0], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 0], ["22", 0], ["23", 0]]}]
```

Comment: Please provide an expected outcome.

Comment: Sorry. I added an expected result.

Comment: Side Note: "distribuitions" is spelled "distributions" (you have an extra "i" after the "u")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty: keep everything as it is, only replace this line

```
hours.first.zip(attendance.transpose.map { |col| col.reduce(:/) })
```

by this

```
hours.first.zip(attendance.transpose.map { |col| col.reduce(:/) rescue 0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edata = entrance[:data].to_h
distribuitions.map do |hash|
  hash.map do |k, v|
    [k, if k == :data
          v.to_h.merge(edata) { |_, v1, v2| v2.zero? ? 0 : v1.to_f/v2.to_f }
        else
          v
        end]
  end.to_h
end
```

Comment: Putting an if inside an array with a ternary inside a block is unusually cruel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `0/0` is to be regarded as zero. For `n/0` I will return `:zd` when `n` is non-zero.

```
distros  = [{:name=>"cardio", :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 3], ["08", 2]]},
            {:name=>"shape",  :data=>[["06", 0], ["07", 2], ["08", 1]]}]
entrance =  {:name=>"gym",    :data=>[["08", 2], ["07", 0], ["06", 0]]}
```

First create a hash `g` from `entrance[:data]`.

```
g = entrance[:data].to_h
  #=> {"06"=>0, "07"=>0, "08"=>2}
```

Next, prepare a helper method.

```
def divide_em(num, den)
  if den.zero?
    num.zero? ? 0.0 : :zd
  else
    num.to_f/den
  end
end

divide_em(1, 2) #=> 0.5
divide_em(0, 0) #=> 0.0
divide_em(3, 0) #=> :zd
```

Lastly, perform the divisions.

```
distros.map { |h| h.merge(h) { |k,d,_| k==:data ?
  d.map { |id, num| divide_em(num, g[id]) } : d } }
  #=> [{:name=>"cardio", :data=>[0, :zd, 1.0]}, 
  #    {:name=>"shape",  :data=>[0, :zd, 0.5]}]
```

Note: 1) the order of the arrays in `entrance[:data]` need not correspond to the order of the arrays in each `h[:data]` where `h` is an element of `distros`; and 2) `distros` remains unchanged.

This employs the version of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is of course all keys. See the doc for details, particularly the definitions of the resolution block's three variables (here `k`, `d` and `_`, the underscore indicating that the third block variable is not used).